# Fine-tune the XGboost classifier using optuna

Tags: python

I am trying to fine-tune the xgboost classifier with optuna using the following code in the link https://www.kaggle.com/code/para24/xgboost-stepwise-tuning-using-optuna/notebook  and I receive this error. I tried my best to look around in the internet and did not find any solution. Can someone please tell me what might be the issue. I am using different dataset and the target variable has 0's and 1's just like 'Survived' in the example dataset in the link. The issue is in "in[25]"
"def precision_recall_plot(y_true, y_probs, label, compare=False, ax=None):" in the above link.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [26], line 5
      1 xgb_clf_default = XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight=cls_weight,
      2                                 random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
      3 xgb_clf_default.fit(x_train, y_train);
----> 5 xgb_clf_default, xgb_report_default = report(xgb_clf_default, x_train, y_train,
      6                                              x_test, y_test,
      7                                              display_scores=[primary_eval_metric],
      8                                              importance_plot=True,
      9                                              feature_labels=feature_names,
     10                                              confusion_labels=confusion_lbs)

Cell In [16], line 129, in report(clf, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, display_scores, sample_weight, refit, importance_plot, confusion_labels, feature_labels, verbose)
    127 clf_name = clf.__class__.__name__
    128 roc_plot(y_test, y_probs, clf_name, ax=roc_axes)
--> 129 precision_recall_plot(y_test, y_probs, clf_name, ax=pr_axes)
    131 fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=5)
    132 fig.tight_layout()

Cell In [12], line 18, in precision_recall_plot(y_true, y_probs, label, compare, ax)
     16     axis.legend(loc='lower left')
     17 else:
---> 18     sns.lineplot(thresh, p, label='Precision', ax=axis)
     19     axis.set_xlabel('Threshold')
     20     axis.set_ylabel('Precision')

TypeError: lineplot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

I added self in class definition and it shows error regarding label in these lines in in[25]

```
sns.lineplot(thresh, p, label='Precision', ax=axis)
axis.set_xlabel('Threshold')
axis.set_ylabel('Precision')
```

error:  precision_recall_plot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'

Comment: Try passing a pd.DataFrame to lineplot and  specify your colnames in arguments: x, y (strings) according to https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html

Comment: @Tom Thank you very much for your response. I had seen the link several times before and tried changing things. It has something to do with label as in above errors. Not sure.

Comment: Update: I resolved it by removing the 'thresh' argument and by adding the following lines.  axis_twin = axis.twinx()
        sns.lineplot(r, color='limegreen', label='Recall', ax=axis_twin)
        axis_twin.set_ylabel('Recall')
        axis_twin.set_xlabel('Threashold')